# Filtering data where one field is above value depending on another field criteria

Tags: oracle

Not sure how to title this (therefore didn't get lucky when trying to search for an answer), but let's say I've got a table as follows:

```
Product Quality Source
P1      0.80    Provider1
P1      0.75    Provider2
P1      0.20    Provider3
P1      0.83    Provider4
P1      0.60    Provider5
P2      0.45    Provider1
P2      0.76    Provider2
P2      0.20    Provider3
P2      0.87    Provider4
P3      0.45    Provider1
P3      0.30    Provider2
P3      0.84    Provider4
P3      0.24    Provider5
```

and I only want to keep products that are either Provider1 or Provider3 or has a higher quality than the best of qualities of that product on Provider1 or Provider3. So I'd like to end up with:

```
Product Quality Source
P1      0.80    Provider1
P1      0.20    Provider2
P1      0.83    Provider4
P2      0.45    Provider1
P2      0.76    Provider2
P2      0.20    Provider3
P2      0.87    Provider4
P3      0.45    Provider1
P3      0.84    Provider4
```

I've got quite a bit of data so I'm looking for a smart way to do this.

Brute force would be something like:

`select * from mytable m1 where m1.Source = 'Tier1' or m1.Source > (select max(m2.Quality) from mytable m2 where m2.Product = m1.Product and m2.Source = 'Tier1')`

Any suggestion?

Thanks

*Edit1:* I had simplified the problem slightly by omitting that each product could have multiple sources, I've now amended my post.

Using Littlefoot's suggestion:

```
with inter as 
    (
            select m1.product, m1.quality, m1.source,
                    (select max(m2.quality) from mytable m2 
                            where m2.product = m1.product 
                            and m2.source in ('Provider1', 'Provider3')
                    ) max_quality
            from mytable m1
    )
select product, quality, source from inter
    where source in ('Provider1', 'Prodiver3') 
    or quality > max_quality;
```

I will need to see if that is fast enough when I run the request on the whole table  (~hundreds of thousands of rows).

Answer (score 1):

One option might be

```
SQL> with test (product, quality, source) as
  2    (select 'P1', 0.8,  'Tier1' from dual union all
  3     select 'P2', 0.75, 'Tier2' from dual union all
  4     select 'P3', 0.2,  'Tier2' from dual union all
  5     select 'P4', 0.83, 'Tier2' from dual union all
  6     select 'P5', 0.6,  'Tier1' from dual
  7    ),
  8  inter as
  9    (select product, quality, source,
 10      (select max(quality) max_qual from test
 11       where source = 'Tier1'
 12      ) max_qual
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select product, quality, source
 16  From inter
 17  where source = 'Tier1'
 18    or quality > max_qual;

PR    QUALITY SOURC
-- ---------- -----
P1         ,8 Tier1
P4        ,83 Tier2
P5         ,6 Tier1

SQL>
```

Or:

```
  <snip>
  8  inter as
  9    (select product, quality, source,
 10      max(case when source = 'Tier1' then quality else 0 end) over (order by null) max_qual
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select product, quality, source
 14  from inter
 15  where source = 'Tier1'
 16    or quality > max_qual;

PR    QUALITY SOURC
-- ---------- -----
P1         ,8 Tier1
P4        ,83 Tier2
P5         ,6 Tier1

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot. I'm not sure I understand the first part. Why :
`    with test (product, quality, source) as`
`    (select 'P1', 0.8,  'Tier1' from dual union all`
`    select 'P2', 0.75, 'Tier2' from dual union all`
`    select 'P3', 0.2,  'Tier2' from dual union all`
`    select 'P4', 0.83, 'Tier2' from dual union all`
`    select 'P5', 0.6,  'Tier1' from dual`
`    ),`
rather than:
`    with test (product, quality, source) as`
`    (select product, quality, source from mytable)`
(this would make sense because I actually have more than those 3 fields in mytable)

Comment: I used CTE (a common-table-expression, the WITH factoring clause) to "simulate" a table. I used list of columns I saw in your example. As you didn't post CREATE TABLE nor INSERT INTO statements, I used CTE to get some data to be able to write a query which will return *something*. No problem if you have additional columns, if they don't affect the result.

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot. I’ve edited my post and used your suggestion to try and answer the new version of the problem.